# Exporting Treeview data to excel sheet using C#

Tags: c#, listview, tree, treeview, windows

I am using Visual Studio 2010. I have a form which has a treeview control which generate values from an xml file. When I select a particular treeview node, I need to export the selected node data and its child nodes to an excel sheet as rows and columns.

Could any one guide me how can I proceed with this?

Appreciate your immediate response.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through the children of the select node then add to exel workbook

this code show how to get to the children of the select node

```
foreach(TreeNode node in yourTreeview.SelectedNode.Nodes)
{
      // write code to export data to excel.
}
```

You can read for exporting data to excel 
  [How can I export data to an Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840099/how-can-i-export-data-to-excel-file)