# Export excel data in C# win App

Tags: c#, excel, export

When export data, Excel file is empty!
I am beginner and I can't solve the problem.
This is my code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)Excel.ActiveSheet;
        Excel.Visible = true;


        ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Row";
        ws.Cells[1, 2] = "نام";
        ws.Cells[1, 3] = "نام خانوادگی";
        ws.Cells[1, 4] = "تاریخ ورود";
        ws.Cells[1, 5] = "تاریخ خروج";
        ws.Cells[1, 6] = "زمان ورود";
        ws.Cells[1, 7] = "زمان خروج";
        ws.Cells[1, 8] = "تاریخ فارسی";


        for(int j=2;j<=dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            for(int i=2;i<=5;i++)
            {
                ws.Cells[j, 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[j - 2].Cells[i - 1].Value;
            }
        }
```

Result :
[Current Excel snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ858.png)

Comment: We are missing the code for saving and closing  the worksheet.

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840099/how-can-i-export-data-to-excel-file

Answer (score 0):

Payam Hayati! You did not save the file or worksheet and that is why you did not get the desired output. As an example, see the below:

```
public class Product
{
   public string Code { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Above is a class to demonstrate how to save or export an excel file. Now we'll create a collection of objects as follows in a list:

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>()
{
  new Product { Code = "1234", Name = "Denim Jeans", Price = 2000 },
  new Product { Code = "123456", Name = "Denim Jacket", Price = 3000 },
  new Product { Code = "12345678", Name = "Nike Sneakers", Price = 4000 }
};
```

Now in a method, put the following code: (Remember to add reference of **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll**)

```
public void ExportToExcel(List<Product> products)
{
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

  excel.Workbooks.Add();  //Create empty workbook
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet workSheet = excel.ActiveSheet; //Create Worksheet from active sheet

  try
  {
    workSheet.Cells[1, "A"] = "Code"; //Set the header
    workSheet.Cells[1, "B"] = "Name";
    workSheet.Cells[1, "C"] = "Price";

    int row = 2; //Start the row
    foreach (Product items in products) //Iterate through a loop
    {
        workSheet.Cells[row, "A"] = items.Code;
        workSheet.Cells[row, "B"] = items.Name;
        workSheet.Cells[row, "C"] = string.Format("{0} Price", items.Price);

        row++;
    }

    workSheet.Range["A1"].AutoFormat(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRangeAutoFormat.xlRangeAutoFormatClassic1);

    string fileName = string.Format(@"{0}\DatainExcel.xlsx", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory));

    workSheet.SaveAs(fileName); //Save data in the file

    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("The file '{0}' is saved successfully!", fileName));
}

catch (Exception exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Exception", "Problem while saving Excel file!\n" + exception.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}

finally
{
    excel.Quit(); //This is to quit excel

    if (excel != null)
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);

    if (workSheet != null)

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workSheet);

    excel = null;
    workSheet = null;

    GC.Collect(); //This is to force garbage cleaning
  }
 }
```

And you are done. Give a try.